# How to access functions and data of one class in other class in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, web

I am new to PHP OOPs and I have a problem where I want to access the member data and functions of one class in another class. I google it but not getting any perfect solution.

Here is my example code:

```
class school{
 public function teacher()
 {
   $teacher_name='Ali Raza';

 }
 public static function students()
     {

       echo"STUDENT DATA: Jhon Deo";

     }


}
 class library{
     public function teacher_name()
     {
      // Now here i want to acces the name of teacher form above class function teacher.

     }
public function student_name()
         {
      // Now here i want to access the member function(students) from school class.

         }
    }
```

I am new here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create an attribute `$techer_name=""`, then create a function in class `school` that returns the techer name.

Comment: Please read the theory first, because you must have a basic knowledge (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for accessing function of class school into class library function:

```
class school {
    public function teacher()
    {
        $teacher_name='Ali Raza';

    }

    public function students()
    {
        echo"STUDENT DATA: Jhon Deo";
    }
}

class library {
    public function teacher_name()
    {
        // Now here i want to acces the name of teacher form above class function teacher.
    }

    public static function student_name()
    {
        echo School::students();
    }
}
```

Comment: my function is static i forgot to add it in code my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the class that has the data you want to access. Or, you can define the data static and access it without instantiating.

Take a look at this:

```
class library{
 private $getTeacherInstance;
 public function teacher_name()
 {
    if(!$getTeacherInstance) // if instance is not created
      $this->getTeacherInstance = new school(); // then get a new instance
    return $this->getTeacherInstance->teacher(); // call the method exists inside `school class`
 }
}
```

Make your teacher() function to return some data like "Teacher's name"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This is a php class that inherits the from school class to library class.

The main function will access the data needed through the library class that takes the data from school class.

Hope this helps

```
<?php

class school{

  public $teacher_name;
  public $students_name;

  public function getTeacherName(){
     return $this->teacher_name;
  }

  public function setTeacherName(){
    $this->teacher_name = "Ali Raza";
  }

  public function getStudentName(){
     return $this->students_name;
  }

  public function setStudentName(){
     $this->students_name = "Ali Raza";
  }


}

/**
* 
*/
class library extends school
{
    //this will get the value from class school
}

function showAll(){
  $showAll = new library();
  $showAll->setTeacherName();
  echo "Teacher Name: " . $showAll->getTeacherName() . '<br>';
  echo "Studnet Name: ". $showAll->getStudentName();
}

showAll();
```